# On the Value of Definite Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to evaluate it,

$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2} dx dy$

No idea which reduction to use. Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am hoping for
$$\int_{-2}^2\int_0^{\sqrt{\color{red}{4}-x^2}}(x^2+y^2)^{1/3}d\color{red}{y}d\color{red}{x}=\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^2r^{2/3}r\,dr\,d\theta=\frac38\pi\cdot2^{8/3}$$